# How do I implement Table Per Hierarchy in entity framework 6 on an existing database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a table with a few one to many and many to many relationships to other tables.

```
public DbSet<EngineeringPd> EngineeringPds { get; set; }
```

If I change the dbset to the new base class then the project doesn't build

```
public DbSet<CorePds> CorePds { get; set; }
```

Should the mapping to related tables be

```
EntityTypeConfiguration<EngineeringPd>
```

or

```
EntityTypeConfiguration<CorePds>
```

How can I get this to update properly?
Also is it possible to only map some tables to the sub classes?

errors
error CS1061: 'NewWhelenPortal.Models.ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'EngineeringPds' and no extension method 'EngineeringPds' accepting a first argument of type 'Portal.Models.ApplicationDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

from

```
    public IQueryable<EngineeringPd> All
    {
        get { return context.EngineeringPds; }
    }
```

Comment: what are the compiler errors?

Comment: Could you show your db structure?